# Three team will/would be

Tags: difference, will-would

Here's an explanation about the phrase "two-horse race".

> (a) Two-horse race

> A close or tight battle between two teams for the title (three teams **would be** a three-horse race, and so on).
> [Two-horse race](https://languagecaster.com/football-glossary-two-horse-race/)

My question is what's the difference if I say "three team **will be**...?

Comment: one team, two teams, three teams, and members of a team.

Answer (score -1):

**three-team** could be grammatical in a number of situations. For example:

> It's a three-team race for first place in the league.

That could be said if three teams each had a record of wins and losses that could result in any of them occupying the league's first-place slot, according to how the remaining games play out.

In your question:

> ... what's the difference if I say "three team will be...?

if you meant to type "three-team", you are using an adjective, *three-team*, as the subject of "will be", which is ungrammatical.  Or if you want "team" to be the subject, it must be in the plural, *teams*.

Comment: Thanks TimR. But my question is how does "would" work in the sentence? If substitute "would" for "will", what is the difference?

Comment: As they say in the newspaper industry, "you buried the lede".

Comment: Could you explain how "would" work there? I want to understand it.

Comment: The question has been asked a thousand times here.  Just search for "difference between will and would"